# Calling a function upon button press

Tags: python, function, button, pyqt

I am trying to call function `funcion` when I click `btn_brow_3`. How could I accomplish this?

When running the following code, I receive this error message:
`TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal not "nonetype"`

```
import atexit
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import os                           # Libreria para manejar directorios del sistema operativo

def funcion(a):
    print "Hola mundo" + str(a)

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):               
        
        exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('c:/prueba gui/resource/logo.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
        
        btn_brow_1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Browser...', self)
        btn_brow_1.resize(btn_brow_1.sizeHint())
        btn_brow_1.move(300, 50)
        btn_brow_1.clicked.connect(self.showDialog_points)
        
        btn_brow_2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Dir browser', self)
        btn_brow_2.resize(btn_brow_2.sizeHint())
        btn_brow_2.move(300, 80)
        btn_brow_2.clicked.connect(self.showDialog_indir_stl)
        
        btn_brow_3 = QtGui.QPushButton('Dir browser', self)
        btn_brow_3.resize(btn_brow_3.sizeHint())
        btn_brow_3.move(300, 110)
        btn_brow_3.clicked.connect(self.showDialog_outdir_stl)
        
        
        
        
        btn_brow_4 = QtGui.QPushButton('Crear soportes', self)
        btn_brow_4.setGeometry(20, 145, 250, 25)
        #btn_brow_4.clicked.connect(support.main(fname_points, self.fname_stl_indir, self.fname_stl_outdir))
        btn_brow_4.clicked.connect(funcion(12))  # HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
        
        self.le1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.le1.setGeometry(20, 50, 250,21)
        
        self.le2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.le2.setGeometry(20, 80, 250,21)
        
        self.le3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.le3.setGeometry(20, 110, 250,21)
        
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")
        
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)
        
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Support from points generator')    
        self.show()
        
        
    
    def showDialog_points(self):
        
        self.fname_points = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open points file', '/home')
        self.statusBar().showMessage(str(self.fname_points))
        self.le1.setText(str(self.fname_points))
        self.fname_points = str(self.le1.text())
        print fname_points

    
    def showDialog_indir_stl(self):
        
        self.fname_stl_indir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select STL INPUT directory', '/home')
        self.statusBar().showMessage(str(self.fname_stl_indir))
        self.le2.setText(str(self.fname_stl_indir))
        self.fname_stl_indir = str(self.le2.text())
        print fname_stl_indir 

    def showDialog_outdir_stl(self):
        
        self.fname_stl_outdir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select STL OUTPUT directory', '/home')
        self.statusBar().showMessage(str(self.fname_stl_outdir))
        self.le3.setText(str(self.fname_stl_outdir))
        self.fname_stl_outdir = str(self.le3.text())
        print fname_stl_outdir 
  
def main():
    
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 29):

Qt signals can have arguments that will be passed to the slots they are connected to; an example would be the new value as an argument in a signal `changed`. Therefore, while you *can* have a slot with arguments, you cannot define the actual values of those when connecting the signal to the slot, as they will be defined when emitting signal.

For defining an argument at connect time, you can use an additional function which does nothing but calling the original function with the defined argument:

```py
def wrapper():
    funcion(12)

def funcion(a):
    print "Hola mundo" + str(a)

[...]
btn_brow_4.clicked.connect(wrapper)
```

As a side note: `wrapper` does not use braces here: the function is not called, but simply passed as an argument to the function `connect`. In your code, you *called* your function `funcion`, which returns nothing (=`None`), which was passed to `connect` in your original code, resulting in the error message you received.

To make that a bit cleaner, you can also use an anonymous function:

```py
btn_brow_4.clicked.connect(lambda: funcion(12))
```

Note that Qt also provides ways of doing this, but (at least for me) the Python variants are easier to read.

**Edit:** Some more information: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/25/passing-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot/

Comment: not Obvious at all, works with multiple inputs BTW. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Try This,

```
def funcion(a):
 print "Hola mundo" + str(a)

[...]
btn_brow_4.clicked.connect(lambda: funcion(12))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below method to access the same:

```
self.connect(btn_brow_4,Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.callingFunction)

def callingFunction():
    function(12)
```

Comment: I'd suggest sticking with new-style signals/slots as used in the OP's code over the old-style variant. See http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html