# Unable to send signal from Button created in Python loop

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt5, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I am trying to create a series of buttons in a loop. Each button gets an id number as it's text and when the button is clicked it is supposed to send the id number to a function that will open an archived order. At this time I just want to print the order number to prove that the signal works and each button is connected to the correct order number.

```
ui.cmdOpen = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ui.frOrdHist)
ui.cmdOpen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(269, line1Y, 61, 22))
ui.cmdOpen.setText(iOrderId)
ui.cmdOpen.setObjectName("cmdOpen")
ui.cmdOpen.clicked.connect(lambda button=ui.cmdOpen:displayOrder(ui, button))


def displayOrder(ui, button):
    i = button.text()
    print(i)
```

When I click the button, I get an error message that says "boolean object has no text attribute"

I tried passing the order number directly and it would print "False" so still a boolean. I don't know where the boolean is coming from, it must be something wrong in the signal.

Comment: If you're creating buttons in a loop, you may be running into a problem with closures.  It will be easier to diagnose if you include the loop code

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080731/call-a-function-when-a-button-is-pressed-pyqt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [clicked signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) always sends the *checked* state of the button. So this will overwrite your default `button` argument with a boolean value, which is why you get the AttributeError (i.e. because `bool` doesn't have that method). You should instead make the connection like this:

```
ui.cmdOpen.clicked.connect(
    lambda checked, button=ui.cmdOpen: displayOrder(ui, button))
```

---

PS: another common source of this issue is the [triggered signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) of QAction. If you ever find your slots receiving unexpected inputs, it's always worth checking the Qt Docs to see if the signature of the signal has any parameters with default values - i.e. that look something like this:

```
void QSomeClass::someSignal(bool param = false)
```