# PySide-6.6: clicked signal sends extra boolean argument to slot

Tags: python, pyside2, signals-slots, pyside6

I just upgraded PySide6 (PySide6==6.6.0 from 6.2.2) and a new behavior is wreaking havoc with my GUI program. Every place where I have a `clicked` signal, the hooked up slot is receiving an extra bool==False argument.

```
x = QPushButton('New', clicked = self.new_append_title)
# ..... add x to my gui

def new_append_title(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    print(f' Args: {args}' )
    print(f' Kwargs: {kwargs}' )
```

This returns
Args: (False,)
Kwargs: {}

Previously with earlier versions I was getting no arguments. I can fix all my code so it takes an extra dummy argument, but does anybody know what is going on here?  I also updated a few other things in my requirements - like moving to python 3.12, so it might not be a PySide issue...

---

In response to ekhumoro I am actually trying to send and argument here. I have tried every permutation I can think of, including the one he gives in his answer below.

```
self.save_button.clicked.connect(lambda *, row=row: self.save_row(row))

def save_row(self, row):
    print(f'row={row})
```

Finally worked. I am not clear on what * does, but it seems to hold the arg from qPushButton signal and therefore it is not necessary to have it in the member function.

Comment: It seems strange that you didn't receive that argument previously, since it's the expected behavior, *unless*: 1. You previously used an empty `@Slot()` decorator and you removed it; 2. There was a bug in that PySide version (or some issue related to the specific Python version); 3. They changed behavior in early PySide6 versions and reverted back in newer ones. The `clicked` signal is *always* emitted with its `checked` argument (default is `False` for uncheckable buttons) and can only be ignored by using an empty `@Slot()` or by using a lambda or `functools.partial()` (with care).

Comment: Note that the PySide behavior is a bit peculiar and different from that of PyQt when dealing with connections, as it normally treats connected functions like they were using the `@Slot` decorator when default (named) parameters exist in the signal (which is the case of the `clicked` signal of every QAbstractButton based class): see [this related answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/66379778). Also, be aware that there are similar issues when using `functools.partial` and keyword arguments, which do *not* override default signal arguments: see [this related post](//stackoverflow.com/q/66364602).

Comment: It's unclear. What do you want exactly? A handler(callback) with no arguments still works fine for ```PySide 6.6.0```. Post a [mre].

Comment: I tried it again with python 3.10 and same issue, so it is the difference between pyside6.2.2 and pyside6.6.0.  I did not know that a non-checkable button would emit a signal  FALSE. I have used this for several earlier versions of pyside as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can indeed reproduce this odd difference in behaviour between various versions of PySide. However, unlike [my previous answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379778/984421), the current issue relates to *how the signal connections are made*. It seems PySide has been highly inconsistent in this regard, whereas PyQt is much more reliable (at least in the few versions I tested with).

The important difference with the current case, is that signal connections made via the `clicked` keyword argument, do not behave the same way as explicit connections made via the `connect` method. The whole sorry mess is detailed below, but the immediate take-home message here is this: to future-proof your PySide code, ***do not ever rely on default signal arguments being silently dropped***. Always assume that some future version will start sending the default arguments, and protect your slots accordingly. This is how PyQt5/6 has always behaved, and it seems likely that PySide6 will eventually do likewise. In my own code, I have most commonly employed keyword-only arguments to work-around this issue, like this:

```py
button.connect(self.slot)
...
def slot(self, *, mykeyword=True):
```

As you will see below, this behaves the same way *across all versions of PySide and PyQt I tested*, and is possibly the least intrusive in terms of API changes and general code-churn. (But see also [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379778/984421) for several other options - with some provisos).

---

Now for the gory details.

Below is a test script that exposes the problems. As you will see from the output, both PySide2 and PySide6 show different behaviour depending on how the signal connection is made, and on the precise version used. The good news is that PySide-6.6.0 shows the same behaviour as PyQt5/6 when making connections via the `clicked` keyword argument. The bad news is that using `connect` shows the same inconsistent behaviour as PySide2. Note also that PySide2 itself shows some differences in how slot arguments are treated: when using `connect(slot)`, the first argument is over-written, whereas with `clicked=slot`, it isn't.

**TEST SCRIPT**:

```py
import sys

if (pkg := sys.argv[1]) == 'ps2':
   from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
elif pkg == 'ps6':
    from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
elif pkg == 'pq6':
    from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
else:
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

try:
    KEYWORD = sys.argv[2] == 'kw'
except:
    KEYWORD = False

print(f'{QtCore.__package__} (Qt-{QtCore.qVersion()}), keyword={KEYWORD}')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])

def slot1(n=2): print(f'slot1: {n=!r}')
def slot2(*args, n=2): print(f'slot2: {args=!r}, {n=!r}')
def slot3(x, n=2): print(f'slot3: {x=!r}, {n=!r}')
def slot4(*, n=2): print(f'slot4: {n=!r}')

for index in range(1, 5):
    slot = globals()[f'slot{index}']
    if KEYWORD:
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(clicked=slot)
    else:
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        button.clicked.connect(slot)
    button.click()
```

**OUTPUT**:

PySide2:

```
$ python3 test-signals.py ps2
PySide2 (Qt-5.15.11), keyword=False
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(), n=2
TypeError: slot3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
slot4: n=2

$ python3 test-signals.py ps2 kw
PySide2 (Qt-5.15.11), keyword=True
slot1: n=2
slot2: args=(), n=2
TypeError: slot3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
slot4: n=2
```

PySide6:

```
$ python3 test-signals.py ps6
PySide6 (Qt-6.2.2), keyword=False
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(), n=2
TypeError: slot3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
slot4: n=2

$ python3 test-signals.py ps6 kw
PySide6 (Qt-6.2.2), keyword=True
slot1: n=2
slot2: args=(), n=2
TypeError: slot3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
slot4: n=2

$ python3 test-signals.py ps6
PySide6 (Qt-6.6.0), keyword=False
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(), n=2
TypeError: slot3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
slot4: n=2

$ python3 test-signals.py ps6 kw
PySide6 (Qt-6.6.0), keyword=True
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(False,), n=2
slot3: x=False, n=2
slot4: n=2
```

PyQt5/6:

```
$ python3 test-signals.py pq6
PyQt6 (Qt-6.6.0), keyword=False
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(False,), n=2
slot3: x=False, n=2
slot4: n=2

$ python3 test-signals.py pq6 kw
PyQt6 (Qt-6.6.0), keyword=True
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(False,), n=2
slot3: x=False, n=2
slot4: n=2

$ python3 test-signals.py pq5
PyQt5 (Qt-5.15.11), keyword=False
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(False,), n=2
slot3: x=False, n=2
slot4: n=2

$ python3 test-signals.py pq5 kw
PyQt5 (Qt-5.15.11), keyword=True
slot1: n=False
slot2: args=(False,), n=2
slot3: x=False, n=2
slot4: n=2
```

Comment: I don't understand why you and the OP want to augment the arguments of a signal handler for the clicked signal of the ```QPushButton```. Can you give a use case? Isn't it simple and bullet-proof if you only assign a void callable?

Comment: Thankyou for the elucidation. I know feel comfortable fixing my code to accept the extra (False) argument.

Comment: @relent95 It's quite common to write an API that takes arguments, and then later on (for entirely separate reasons) want to connect it directly it to a signal. Your "simple" solution then requires *two* APIs: a no-args wrapper slot for the signal, plus a parameterised function to be called by other code. Signals like `clicked` and `triggered` are amongst the most commonly used, so adding such boiler-plate APIs can result in a lot of useless code-churn. Of course, there are various well-known work-arounds (e.g. `lambda`, `partial`, etc) - but none of them are entirely satisfactory.

Comment: @relent95 The real issue here is historical. With old-style signals/slots, you could easily eliminate the default argument by using `SIGNAL('clicked()')`, and when PyQt introduced new-style signals/slots this could be replicated by writing `x.clicked[()].connect(slot)`. But this functionality was later removed, and I don't think PySide ever supported it. In my view, only `x.clicked[bool].connect(slot)` should ever send the argument, whilst the default should always send nothing, since 99.9% of code will want that. Unfortunately, that ship has probably sailed now, but I still live in hope...

Comment: Then, there's no special use case. IMO, connecting a callable which has arguments to the clicked signal of the ```QPushButton``` reduces amount of source code a little bit, but harms the readability and maintainability. The maintenance problem met by the OP is just a good example of that. It's a good time to refactor with the lamda or partial for the OP.

Comment: @relent95 The genuine use-case is simply convenience. Many applications will have hundreds of buttons and actions, so your approach just harms readability and maintainability in a different way. Using solutions like `lambda` and `partial` aren't cost-free, and often introduce unexpected side-effects (e.g. from closures holding on to references). What "special use-case" is there for having both `clicked(checked=false)` ***and*** `toggled(bool)`? It an obvious design-wart to force 99.9% of client code to deal with default arguments that no one will ever need.

Comment: I tried this in about 100 different permutations.  Fail, the only way I seem to be able to get it to work is with partial.  I will put the following in my original comment as I can not format it here.           self.save_button.clicked.connect(lambda *, row=row: self.save_row(row))
TypeError: SemanticTable.save_row() missing 1 required positional argument: 'checked'

Comment: @hawkiboy Your `lambda` has exactly the same signature as the solution I gave in my answer, and it serves the same purpose. The `*` simply means "no more positional arguments after this point", which prevents the signal overwriting your `row` argument. But note that the example I gave does not send any other arguments, so it's obviously not a general solution. If you read my answer more carefully, you will see I provided [a link to a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379778/984421) which covers this other use-case (which is different to the original one shown in your question).