# how can i go over different functions using for loop and .format for my code below?

Tags: python

I am working on a basic calculator using PyQt5. I have a class to create buttons so I don't have to do it manually each time. I defined 16 functions, but I couldn't manage to attach these functions on the buttons using `.format`.

```py
funclistq = ["sum", "takeaway", "multiply", "divide", "seven", "eight",
             "nine", "clear", "four", "five", "six", "zero", "one",
             "two", "three", "ok"]

for i in range(16):
  self.button.clicked.connect(self.{}.format(funclistq[i]))
```

Comment: Not what you asked about, but could you explain the `self.{}` part to me? I'm not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: i guess that part is broken.  i was trying to use format here  and normally you need something like this :  print( "if {}  then {}".format("you are thirsty","drink some water") .       i was trying to iterate through my list with that part.

Comment: unfortunately i can't use a string after "self." part.

Comment: So i think you have confused what format will do. format is to apply to strings.  what you need to do is pass a handle to the function. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080731/calling-a-function-upon-button-press)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.format()` is only for strings. What you want is a dynamic attribute lookup, which you can do with `getattr`.

Also note that in Python, a `for` loop can loop directly over the items in a list, without having to use indices.

```py
for func_name in func_list_q:
    func = getattr(self, func_name)
    self.button.clicked.connect(func)
```

---

On a somewhat related note: if you're on Python 3.6 or newer and using `.format()` for strings, I bet you'll really enjoy [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). They make formatting much more convenient and readable!

Comment: thanks for this answer. it really helped me since i know where to look at now. my project is a beginner one and i am trying to improve my coding skills with little tasks like this one. i went with a simple solution while waiting for an answer. `if i == 0 :
                self.button.clicked.connect(self.sum)
            elif i == 1 :
                self.button.clicked.connect(self.takeaway)
            elif i == 2 :
                self.button.clicked.connect(self.multiply)` etc.